# Firefox add-on access popup script from background/content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am in the process of translating my Chrome extension into a Firefox extension. I am having a problem though.

My extension requires stored data for the extension to be loaded in the content script as well as in the popup page. I have no problem with this in my Chrome extension. I just use `chrome.storage` to pass and retrieve storage and I can use that both in my content and popup scripts with ease.

With Firefox, I'm having a having a hard time figuring out exactly what I have to do different. I got that I can't use `chrome.storage` and rather use the

`const storage = require("sdk/simple-storage").storage;`

thing, but I need to use this in both the content script and the script for the popup page. I researched and found I can't use the require function more than once, so my question is, would I be able to share the variable between the popup script and the content script? I need the storage from both sides and there isn't any other way I can see to make the extension work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use message-passing to have the content script the main addon communicate with each other.

Two possible approaches:

- send down the data in advance if it's not too large / doesn't affect too many tabs and also push down updates as they happen. this provides superior read latency at the potential cost of increased memory footprint and increased cost of writes.
- request individual data items on demand. this is better for frequently-written or large items of data but comes at the cost of higher latency per request.

You also might want to look at [webextensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). storage in content is not yet supported there either, but it probably will be in the future.

Comment: The only api my extension uses is storage :( but if what you're saying means I can pass a variable with all the data I need from the popup script to the content script then that's all I need.